# Windows build with -mwindows flag no executable

Tags: c++, windows, build

I had problems building a program I'm working on in C++ because MinGW files and Windows SDK file were conflicting and I found the solution by adding the `-mwindows` flag for the linker to the build options. This works: now I can build the project without errors.
But now the compiler doesn't output any executable file (.exe).
My question is: why? And what exactly the `-mwindows` does?

**Edit:** The output of the build phase is reported in a text file in this Dropbox folder (I couldn't copy it here because it's more than 2800 lines): https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1ud85a3fktb62v6/AAB3L8Vp5VcKPJqCPyOXtzdca?dl=0

I already tried to create a new 'Hello World' project and build it: the executable file is created and I can run it, so I think the cause of my problem is that flag and not a particular setting on my IDE (CLion).

Comment: Please show the detailed output from the build stages - both compile and link.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't provide it before, but since the output is more than 2800 lines I had to copy it in a text file and upload it on Dropbox; here is the link
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1ud85a3fktb62v6/AAB3L8Vp5VcKPJqCPyOXtzdca?dl=0